# Antithetic variate for Chi-squared distribution?

Tags: sampling, simulation, monte-carlo, chi-squared-distribution

I am using antithetic sampling for variance reduction. I know for standard normal $z$, it's antithetic variate is $-z$ ($1-U$ for uniform etc).  But I cannot figure out what would be antithetic variate for samples from chi-squared distribution since I don't find symmetry.

Also for $t$ distribution, would it be $-t$? Since it is symmetric around the origin?

Comment: Your definition of an antithetic variable seems too limited to make the question answerable.  But if you follow the definition used at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183453, an answer should be clear.

Comment: I understand that I can get a general antithetic variable for any distribution D following the steps : Step1) Generate u from U(0,1)  Step2) Get Value from inverse cdf  Dinv(u) Step3) Get value from inverse cdf  Dinv(1-u) and then take average. But i wanted to know if there is any definite closed form answer for chi-squared like there is for uniform and normal.

Comment: Yes: it's called the incomplete gamma function.  Statisticians know it better as the chi-squared quantile function or inverse chi-squared cumulative distribution.  Any general-purpose statistical software can compute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the definition of antithetic variable from [Calculating integral with antithetic variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183453/calculating-integral-with-antithetic-variables), that is, $x_i^*$ is the antithetic variable for $x_i$ when $F(x_i^*) + F(x_i)=1$, $F$ the cdf, the answer should be clear. For simulation of the chi-squared random variable $X$ use the inversion method, see [How does the inverse transform method work?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184325/how-does-the-inverse-transform-method-work).

So the algorithm is, with $F$ the chi-squared cdf:

- $U\sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$
- $V=1-U$
- $X=F^{-1}(U)$
- $X^* = F^{-1}(V)$ is the antithetic variable.